# openstreetmap is not showing complete map inside div

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-blade

My Code for Map is here:
when i click on Span text then it shows the map but not full.

```
var latitude = document.querySelector('#lati').value;//$('#lati').val();
var longitude = document.querySelector('#longi').value;//$('#longi').val();
var open_address = document.querySelector('#open_address').value;//$('#open_address').val();
// console.log(latitude);console.log(longitude);console.log(open_address);

var mapOption = {
    center: [latitude, longitude],
    zoom:10
}

var map = new L.map('expose-map', mapOption);

var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 25
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have simple working code to display single marker on the map using leaflet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Simle marker on the map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;width: 600px;max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    const marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
</script>
```

[`source`](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)

BTW1: if your code from the question don't work, try to isolate core map functionality within your project to find interfering elements (other js or css). That's how devs debug...

BTW2: when you paste following code in the console. What do your see? Is the value float number or text? For coordinates the value needs to be a float number.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('#lati').value);
```

Comment: Your given code is working fine. But still not showing complete map. I have also converted string to float.

Comment: I am fetching laravel blade through ajax. And laravel blade has the map div. in the same blade on top i have put leaflet.css and in the bottom leaflet.js and the above code for map.

Comment: "I am fetching laravel blade through ajax..." is additional info or you want to say "problem solved"? If the problem persist paste the complete source (html) code somewhere so others can view it (as I did) or alternatively "dump DOM over dev console". My tip is that there will be the problem with Scoping and Hoisting.